# How I can use double grouped elements using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

In my project I would like to group double time first by project then group by daily.
For ex: Project X is using for 06.11.2020 (300$ price), for 07.11.2020 (250 $) etc.
I would like to achieve some result like this:

```
[
  {
    projectId: 1,
    projectName: 'Test',
    data: [
      {
        price: 22.000000176,
        startDate: '2020-11-06T00:00:00'
      },
      {
        price: 42.000000176,
        startDate: '2020-11-07T00:00:00'
      },
      {
        price: 62.000000176,
        startDate: '2020-11-08T00:00:00'
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    projectId: 2,
    projectName: 'Test 2',
    data: [
      {
        price: 333.000000176,
        startDate: '2020-11-06T00:00:00'
      },
      {
        price: 3333.000000176,
        startDate: '2020-11-07T00:00:00'
      },
      {
        price: 3333.000000176,
        startDate: '2020-11-08T00:00:00'
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

What I am trying in my code

```
public async Task<List<GroupedBillingInfo>> Handle(GroupedBillingListQuery request,
                CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                var billing = _context.BillingSummaries.Where(x => x.Project.Organization.IsDeleted == false)
                    .AsQueryable();

          

                var demo = billing.ToList();

                var result = demo.GroupBy(x => new {
                        ProjectId = x.ProjectId,
                        Year = x.BeginApply.Year,
                        Month = x.BeginApply.Month,
                        Day = x.BeginApply.Day
                    })
                    .Select(y => new GroupedBillingInfo
                    {
                        ProjectId = y.Key.ProjectId,
                        ProjectName = y.Select(d => d.Project.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                        Data = new List<GroupedBillings>
                        {
                            new GroupedBillings
                            {
                                StartDate = $"{y.Key.Year}/{y.Key.Month}/{y.Key.Day}",
                                Price = y.Sum(s => s.Price)
                            }
                        }
                    }).ToList();

                return result;
            }


        public class GroupedBillings
        {
            public string StartDate { get; set; }
            public decimal Price { get; set; }
        }

        public class GroupedBillingInfo
        {
            public List<GroupedBillings> Data { get; set; }
            public int ProjectId { get; set; }
            public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        }
```

And after this I am getting results:

```
[
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "startDate": "2020/11/6",
        "price": 26.66666688
      }
    ],
    "projectId": 50,
    "projectName": "test-bug"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "startDate": "2020/11/6",
        "price": 33.333333599999996
      }
    ],
    "projectId": 38,
    "projectName": "tcpro-demo"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "startDate": "2020/11/6",
        "price": 40.00000032
      }
    ],
    "projectId": 53,
    "projectName": "loki-test"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "startDate": "2020/11/6",
        "price": 12.000000096
      }
    ],
    "projectId": 64,
    "projectName": "chaos"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "startDate": "2020/11/7",
        "price": 26.66666688
      }
    ],
    "projectId": 64,
    "projectName": "chaos"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "startDate": "2020/11/7",
        "price": 32.000000256
      }
    ],
    "projectId": 50,
    "projectName": "test-bug"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "startDate": "2020/11/7",
        "price": 40.00000032
      }
    ],
    "projectId": 38,
    "projectName": "tcpro-demo"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "startDate": "2020/11/7",
        "price": 48.000000384
      }
    ],
    "projectId": 53,
    "projectName": "loki-test"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "startDate": "2020/11/8",
        "price": 32.000000256
      }
    ],
    "projectId": 64,
    "projectName": "chaos"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "startDate": "2020/11/8",
        "price": 32.000000256
      }
    ],
    "projectId": 50,
    "projectName": "test-bug"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "startDate": "2020/11/8",
        "price": 40.00000032
      }
    ],
    "projectId": 38,
    "projectName": "tcpro-demo"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "startDate": "2020/11/8",
        "price": 48.000000384
      }
    ],
    "projectId": 53,
    "projectName": "loki-test"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "startDate": "2020/11/9",
        "price": 17.333333472
      }
    ],
    "projectId": 64,
    "projectName": "chaos"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "startDate": "2020/11/9",
        "price": 18.666666816
      }
    ],
    "projectId": 50,
    "projectName": "test-bug"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "startDate": "2020/11/9",
        "price": 23.333333519999996
      }
    ],
    "projectId": 38,
    "projectName": "tcpro-demo"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "startDate": "2020/11/9",
        "price": 28.000000224
      }
    ],
    "projectId": 53,
    "projectName": "loki-test"
  }
]
```

So in short I would like (project and inside object -> daily datetimes and price sum,
Project x -> (06nov2020 -> price 300 || 07nov2020 -> price 100)

Comment: what exactly is your problem? I don't really understand your expected result. It sounds like you need a second grouping or ordering there, but I am not sure

Comment: @MongZhu after getting projects in my case it will be always 4 result but data collection will be more results, for ex, project x, daily price sum, for 6th november it is 300 for ex price, then next day some price sum, then next day and etc. all inside data collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not group it at once. You want select a records with unique projectId, and group by date. It should be two different groupings instead

```
            var result = demo
                .GroupBy(x => new {
                    ProjectId = x.ProjectId,
                    Year = x.BeginApply.Year,
                    Month = x.BeginApply.Month,
                    Day = x.BeginApply.Day
                })
                .GroupBy(x => new {
                    ProjectId = x.Key.ProjectId
                })
                .Select(y => new GroupedBillingInfo
                {
                    ProjectId = y.Key.ProjectId,
                    ProjectName = y.First().Select(d => d.Project.Name).First(),
                    Data = y.Select(z => new GroupedBillings
                    {
                        StartDate = $"{z.Key.Year}/{z.Key.Month}/{z.Key.Day}",
                        Price = z.Sum(s => s.Price)
                    }).ToList()
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: I accepted an answer because it shows correct result, but after testing some days, it is not calculating correct price.I think in select something not correct

Comment: I see no errors, it simply sums everything in a group. If it's not the result you expect, it maybe a problem of a GroupBy expression (same ProjectId but not ProjectName, or maybe a dates differs by time).
In order to trace it you can use GroupBy(...).Select().GroupBy().Select(). In first you are grouping by StartDate then selecting a startdate, price, projectId, projectName. Then you can group it by ProjectId and ProjectName and select GroupedBillingInfos. It's more obvious and simple simple. Once again, Sum() always works right and if it's not then check a GroupBy expression.

Comment: You should check how your time is interpreted. I see it's ISO 8061 time without timezone. When interpreting it as a local time it could work in unexpected way - like '2020-11-06T00:00:00' being interpreted as DateTime (2020, 11, 5, 23, 00, 00) by some timezone conversion. So it's 2020/11/5 now not 2020/11/6.